# How to print HTML String in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make an invoice in html and want to print directly without preview in a dialog box. I have created a partial view of ASCX type and render as a HTML string in a controller in MVC. Now I want to print the output of this HTML string.

My code is like this:

```
public void Print(int saleId)
{

        var doc = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        string defaultPrinterName = settings.PrinterName;
        doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = defaultPrinterName;
        //doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
        //doc.Print();
        doc.PrintPage += (sender, args) => ProvideContent(saleId, args);

        doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperA0", 460, 480);
        doc.Print();
}

public ActionResult ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
        string ret = RenderPartialToString("~/Areas/PointOfSale/Views/POSSaleItemUI/POSSaleItemReport.ascx", sender);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
        ret,
        new Font("Arial", 12),
        Brushes.Black,
        e.MarginBounds.Left,
        e.MarginBounds.Top);
        return View("test");
}

public static string RenderPartialToString(string controlName, object viewData)
{
        ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage() { ViewContext = new ViewContext() };

        viewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
        viewPage.Controls.Add(viewPage.LoadControl(controlName));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                viewPage.RenderControl(tw);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you looking to print the html code itself rather than the rendering of it?

Comment: Do note that you cannot print to the user's printer from server side code

Comment: Yes The Muffin Man. I have renderd the partial view as a html string now i want to print the output of this Htmlstring